# Динамический код в Spring Boot приложении

Tags: java, spring, groovy

Появилась задача разработать простой сервис, который переодически получает из базы данных clob'ы с файлами, и в зависимости от их типа, обрабатывает их. Типов файлов с десяток, обработка с одной стороны простая, с другой - сильно отличается в зависимости от типа. Можно, конечно, сделать десяток реализаций класса обработчика и обновлять приложение, если появятся новые типы.

Но, может быть, возможно динамически для каждого типа файла подгружать подходящий обработчик (Groovy или откомпилированный класс) из внешнего источника? Стоит ли с этим связываться? И как, в таком случае, из скрипта получить доступ до бинов основного приложения, нет ли с этим проблем?

Comment: Если Вы будете подгружать обработчик из внешнего источника, то как Вы будете покрывать его тестами? На мой взгляд, это имеет смысл, если Вам необходимо предоставить "потребителю/пользователю" сервиса расширять поддерживаемые типы файлов. Причём, Вы сейчас уже видите несколько потенциальных проблем связанных с таким подходом, но сколько Вы не видите? Так в чём проблема с обновлением сервиса/приложения при добавлении поддержки новых типов?

Answer (score 2):

Ваша идея имеет право на жизнь и я видел успешные примеры подобного решения.

Исполнение на лету нужного Groovy-скрипта для каждого случая задача весьма типовая, особенно в DevOps.

Чтобы скрипт мог работать с экземплярами Spring-бинов, их необходимо передавать в скрипт явным образом через механизм биндинга:

```
Binding bindings = new Binding();
bindings.setProperty('myBean', beanInstance); 
GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(bindings);
shell.evaluate("myBean.myBeanMethod()"); // здесь переданная строка - это уже скрипт
```